# Use of EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR attribute

Tags: graphics, opengl-es-2.0

What is the use of EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR attribute in eglCreateImageKHR(EGLDisplay dpy,EGLContext ctx,EGLenum target,EGLClientBuffer buffer,const EGLint *attrib_list)
function? Does it mean that the egl image is double buffered and we can reuse the pixel data for some post processing?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_image_base.txt):

> If the value of attribute EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR is EGL_FALSE (the default), then all pixel data values associated with  will be undefined after eglCreateImageKHR returns.
>
> If the value of attribute EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR is EGL_TRUE, then all pixel data values associated with  are preserved."

In other words, if you want to be sure that the content of the original image to be preserved once the eglImage has been created, you need to set this flag to TRUE (else an implementation is free to discard the original content).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.In my application the egl image is updated for each frame so if set EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR to EGL_TRUE can we reuse the pixel data values of the previous frame in the current frame? If yes please can you let me know how to do the same

Comment: Any update you make to the contents of EGLImage after it has been created will be preserved no matter what the value of EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR is. The only think that is affected by this flag is whether updates made to the source object (like a texture or a pixmap that the EGLImage is created from) will be preserved when the EGLImage is created.